# Extracting particular columns from a json converted csv file using powershell, or from the initial json file itself

Tags: json, powershell, shell, csv

I had been given a simple Json file which had to be converted to csv. I did so using powershell. The converted csv file has 5 columns out of which I need to extract the 1st and the 5th and then print it in the powershell console and assign it to a variable of a shell code via the batch file.

These are the Csv columns:
[CSV columns imported from json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQXho.jpg)

Only the headers 'name' and 'last_modified' have to be extracted and assigned to a variable or only printed in the powershell console.

This is the shell command in batch file ([cygwin command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyHCS.jpg)) in which the column values (via a new csv or directly) have to be assigned to the %2 part.

IF in case this is not possible, just the 'name' and the 'last_modified' keys directly from json have to be assigned to %2 part of the cygwin code.

I have tried  importing the csv in powershell and assigning it to $A which shows this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncnjF.jpg)

I have tried using this command as well,

```
PS D:\> $A | Get-Member name, last_modified -View Extended
```

but it only shows the first 'name' and the first 'last_modified' value from the csv.

My apologies if this is a very basic question, I am completely new to powershell and batch programming.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code - cut and paste the text into your question instead and format it with "code fences" - i.e. a line containing three backticks before and after the code. This will make it easier for other people to try to reproduce your issue, and you'll be more likely to get an answer as a result.

Comment: `Get-Member name, last_modified` --> `Select-Object name, last_modified`

Answer (score 1):

Get-Member will return only 1 row, you should be using Select-Object as Theo points out in his comment.

Try this to see the difference

```
$csv = Get-Service

$csv | Get-Member Status, Name #Returns 2 columns but only 1 row

$csv | Select-Object Status, Name #Returns 2 columns and all the rows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'Select-Object' worked! Now all that's left is to transfer these values to the %2 variable from the cygwin command in the batch file.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Dont forget to set the answer as correct so future users with this issue know it has been solved :)